# Disk size converting CSV to MySQL (MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, csv

I am looking for a ballpark estimate of the size of the database tables after I have converted the current CSV files to MyISAM tables. I know the file size of the CSV's and I need an estimate of the filesize of the MyISAM. I guess it will be bigger, because of indexes (just 1 simple index is enough), but how much? Is it about 2 times, 10 times or 50 times?

Comment: without an idea of what your data looks like, we can't even begin to guess any more accurately than you.  How about trying to convert a small percentage and see how much space you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're looking for capacity-planning size data to give to your server wrangler.

If your CSV files total less than about 200-300 megabytes in size, just tell her "two gigabytes or less."

If your CSV files are larger than that, you are definitely going to need to run some trials to figure this out.  Notice that indexes aren't necessarily smaller than the data they index, and that they can grow larger faster than linearly.

If you are wrangling with your server wrangler about any amount of disk space less than a couple of gigabytes, then it's unfortunate evidence that your organization is short of money and talent.

In this case you're going to have to prove it to them: load the database on your personal computer, measure the size of the myISAM files, and tell them what you came up with.